# OpenGL - Using transformation matrix to determine projection onto a plane

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I have an OpenGL rendering, which is rectangular, i.e., has no thickness. With UI control, a number of transformations can be applied to the rendering, such as:

- translation
- resizing
- rotation (around arbitrary pivot position), etc.

At any point in time, I can get the transformation matrix, which gives me the cumulative effect of any of the aforementioned transformations applied.

How can I use the transformation matrix to determine the distance between the origin and the projection of any point on the rendering (say, the centre) onto the z-plane?

Comment: Here is a pointer: `0xDEADBEEF` not sure if it's helpful though ;)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are familiar with matrix & vector algebra...

Conceptualy you should do something like this:

```
float Distance(int width, int height const mat4& TransformMatrix, const vec2& center)
{
    vec4 point(center,0,1);
    vec4 transformed = TransformMatrix * point;
    float w = transformed.w;
    if (abs(transformed.x)>w || abs(transformed.y)>w || abs(transformed.z)>w)
        return -1.0; // point is out of clipping volume
    vec4 projected = transformed / transformed.w;
    projected.x *= width *0.5;
    projected.y *= height *0.5;
    // assuming origin point is in viewport center
    return length(projected.x,projected.y);
}
```

- width, height are dimensions of your viewport
- TransformMatrix - should be product of ProjectionMatrix and ModelViewMatrix
- center - point of your interest in local 'object' coordinates.

If you are using OpenGL < 3.0 or OpenGL ES < 2.0 then above matrices can be determined by:

```
float modelview[16], projection[16];
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview);
glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);
```

Viewport dimensions are available in all OpenGLs:

```
int viewport[4]; // width = viewport[2], height = viewport[3]
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
```

You could also use some oldskull GLU functions:
gluProject() -> calculates point position transformed by ModelView & Projection and viewport in pixels.